# Laravel: problems with rendering sections (->renderSections) and content section

Tags: php, laravel, view, render

it seems quite simple. i have a controller, a class/object and a view for it (show/edit). and i want to render this view in an overview/listing.therefore i have to extract the the 'content' section.

demo.blade.php

```
@extends('mainlayout.main')

@section('content')
Content of the object
@endsection
```

so i use in the overview template (overview.blade.php) the following code

```
$sections = View::make('demo')->renderSections();
echo($sections['content']);
```

what happens? the content here overwrites everything in the section (content) of the overview.blade.php

i also tried to take another name for the section like 'contentnew' and than ! it works.

so my questions?

- should it work with section 'content'? or do i understand something wrong with the template engine?
- why is 'content' handled different than contentnew. simple because it is not parse?

thanks for any help.

t00cg